# htaccess RewriteRule for url alias

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, alias

My website has several files and folders:

```
mywebsite.com/index.php
mywebsite.com/files/...
```

Our users asked me if it would be possible to create url alias like this:

```
mywebsite.com/thisalias -> mywebsite.com/index.php?var=thisalias
```

With other words: if the folder/file "thisalias" doesn't exist, it should redirect. I have tried several code samples from StackOverflow but for some reason it didn't work on my host. Any suggestions? I'm not really good with .htaccess coding.

Comment: 1) Confirm with your hosting company that **mod_rewrite is enabled**; 2) Also confirm if .htaccess files are enabled/allowed and that rewrite rules can be used there (some companies disable them for performance/security purposes).

Comment: Ok I will ask them and keep you up-to-date about the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?var=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I get this: You don't have permission to access / on this server. Should I add the relative server html path before index.php? Or how come?

Comment: Do you have access to server confs? How comes you don't have perms to work with your www dir?

Comment: The website is located at a hosting company, so there is limited access. But I have access to work with my home www dir for sure. ;)

Comment: I don't see why should you have no permission to access but try get rid of RewriteBase / and see what's gonna happen. I can't really give much information because I don't know what is the server config like.